# No such property: scope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Android Studio 4 I got this error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: scope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData

My gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha10'
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing. Can you post stack trace? Mine contains something like this
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: 
No such property: scope for class:com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ProjectVariantState.resolveStrippedNativeLibsPath(ProjectVariantState.groovy:256)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ProjectVariantState.resolvePackagedNativeLibsPath(ProjectVariantState.groovy:240)

Answer (score 124):

I had the same issue. Removing all fabric references in build.gradle solved my case.

you can try to remove

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

and

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
```

lines from your build.gradle file.

Fabrics Crashlytics **deprecated**. If you are using **Fabric Crashlytics** you can replace it with **Firebase Crashlytics**.

Comment: Thanks ycannot, this fix my problem. Android studio 4.0

Comment: you are welcome, if you still want to use crashlytics, you can follow these steps to add firebase crashlytics into your project. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: Thanks @ycannot this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 49):

Update in OCTOBER 2020 :
`Fabric` is deprecated, so remove all plugins and dependencies depend on `Fabric.io`

like :

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'



maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
```

and after deletaion you must add :

```
 classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
```

in your `build.gradle`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Comment: after deletions you must add
 classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0' 
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Comment: two birds with one stone, gradle updated and crashlytics upgraded

Answer (score 46):

I had the same problem, in particular with the the same stack trace as @display name (on the comments).

From there I noticed the reference to Crashlytics. And effectively that was the issue: the old, deprecated, version (from Fabric). Migrating to the new Firebase Crashlytics fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, move from Fabic to Firebase (Google)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Answer (score 20):

Just remove or comment it out. it works for me.

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

and

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
```

from both gradle file.

Comment: Thanks, I don't even know why fabric is integrated in our project)))

Comment: Yes, that's it. My project is too old and I have to remove all expired dependences

Answer (score 8):

Please update your Gradle dependency to:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
```

and in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 6):

This started happening for me when upgrading Android Studio from 4.0.2 to 4.1. Unfortunately, I had to update a branch that still includes fabric, the only way I could get it working was to downgrade android studio and make the fixes and be able to make a new build.

Download old versions here:

Windows: https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/versions

Mac: https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/mac/versions

Comment: You need to change your fabric crashlytics usage with firebase crashlytics. You are going to update android studio anyways. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: I think you missed the part about needing to make an update to a specific branch which still had the old version. Can happen if you work on apps with rolling releases abd the version in the store needs a hotfix and the next version with the new firebase isn't ready.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Fabrics Crashlytics and i got the same error after updating my Android plugin for Gradle to version 4.1:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-rc01'
```

I need to upgrade  gradle plugin to upload native debug symbols to Google play console as stated in this link.
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#native-crash-symbolization

To use Android plugin for gradle version 4.1,
your minimum gradle version needs to be version 6.5.
I used gradle version 6.5.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip
```

Upgrading from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics solved the issue for me, this could be because fabric is not compatible with the newer versions of Android plugin for gradle. For more information on how to upgrade from Fabric crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics. Check out this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Comment: When posting links always do so with care. Just a link is bad practice. In this case maybe a summary of the steps mentioned would be good addition to this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle` dependency in your project, just update to version `2.0.0-beta04` it is helped to me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all that connected with deprecated library such as fabric crashlytics etc.

Answer (score 1):

Updating dependencies in build.gradle (Project level) solved my issue:

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5 to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem with an older project which I was maintaining after a longer period. Problem was that project was still using older gradle scripts, plugins and dependencies.

The biggest problem was fabric.io which is not maintained and compatible with the latest gradle version. Stack trace in build output which contained crashlytics references pointed me to the fabric. I recommend checking it. In your case, it might be related to other plugins.

**Stack trace example:**

```
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.ProjectVariantState$deriveFrom.call(Unknown Source)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.createTaskBuilder(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:301)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.this$2$createTaskBuilder(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.addPluginTasks(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:271)
```

Answer (score -2):

On Android Studio simply open build.gradle (Project) and the IDE should suggest an update to crashlytics, accept that and the error will be gone.

Answer (score -2):

In Project level `build.gradle` Just downgrade the version of dependency `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.5.0'` to your last/lower version was `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'` and

In `"gradle-wrapper.properties"` downgrade the `"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-all.zip"` to last/lower version like `"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip"` .
and sync and run .